# Interacting with local PC files, SAS EG 7.1

Tags: sas

I'm struggling to find a solution to this problem.

The import/export wizard works fine from SAS for pathing to static local and shared drive file locations.

I get stuck trying to use PROC EXPORT so save multiple datasets to different sheets in an Excel workbook for retention policies.

I thought I found a solution that would be great. Referencing a LIBNAME to a local file.

When I run:
""LIBNAME x xlsx 'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\EXISITING_CONSOL.xlsx';""

I get confirmation it worked, but when I reference it or try to view it in the Servers navigation window it errors out.

NOTE: Libref X was successfully assigned as follows:
Engine:        XLSX
Physical Name: C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\EXISITING_CONSOL.xlsx

Current version: 9.04.01M3P062415
Operating System:   LIN X64
---SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files

I would like to use this library method but I'm indifferent to a solution as long as I can save the datasets to a folder path through my PC that I can F3.

I appreciate any direction!

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have here is that SAS can't actually see your `c:\users\...` folder, unless you have a share set up (and since the SAS Server is on Linux, it would have to have a different structure anyway).  The "Import wizard" actually imports it locally (using some .Net code in Enterprise Guide) and then uploads the data to the SAS server.

The normal way this is handled is for you to use a network share that both SAS and your local PC can see - often something like \yourcompany.com\sharename\foldername\ or similar.

If you don't have something like this, then you can use the "Copy Files" task in Enterprise Guide to copy files down locally that are on the server.  See [this blog post](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2020/05/19/copy-files-in-sas-eg/) about it.